# Hard request SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, request, substring

I have a pretty hard request to do in SQL Server 2008, but I'm not able to do the whole...

I have two kind of records :

```
16HENFC******** (8 numbers after more 'FC')
16HEN******* (7 numbers after more 'EN')
```

I have to select the `*` (which are in fact numbers), and add a 0 at the beginning of the second form of record to just have 8 long selected values.

Then I have to insert the result in a empty table.

I think I did the first part which is :

```
SUBSTRING(SELECT mycolumn1 FROM mytable1 WHERE mycolumn1 LIKE '16HENFC%', 5, 8) ;
```

In summary,

I have those records in my column :

```
'16HENFC071052'
'16HEN5130026'
```

I want to select them and transform them to insert those ones in an other column :

```
'05130026'
'FC071052'
```

[EDIT]=>

```
CREATE TABLE nom_de_la_table
(
    colonne1 VARCHAR(250),
    colonne2 VARCHAR(250)
)

INSERT INTO nom_de_la_table (colonne1)
 VALUES
 ('16HEN5138745'),
 ('16HENFC071052v2'),
 ('16HENFC78942878'),
 ('16HEN4830026'),
 ('16HEN7815934'),
 ('16HENFC74859422'),
 ('16HEN9687326'),
 ('16HENFC74889639'),
 ('16HEN9798556');
```

[etc...]

So two different types of records, and I want to insert the result of what you did first with just two records in an other column but for the 956 records of my table. And this is the result with the two examples :

```
'05130026'
'FC071052'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left-Filling a string is a relatively easy request. Here's an example:

```
select right(replicate('0',8) + right(test,len(test)-len('16HEN')),8)
from (
    select '16HENFC071052' as test
    union all
    select '16HEN5130026' as test
    ) z
```

Use replicate to left-fill your string with the amount of digits you wish to end up with. Append your desired string, in this case, slice your prefix off by taking the right X characters where `X = len(target) - len(prefix)`. Finally, take the right characters of the whole string equal to your desired length.

Comment: Wahou ... It works well and I think i start to understand how, but it's pretty hard. I'm not good for SQL, just the basics CRUD. But the two codes are examples, i have to do this for all the codes that look that way 'H16HENFC******' and '16HEN*******', there is 956 records like this in the database. I I need to copy the result of what you did in an other column for the 956 records..

Comment: I also have some diffculties with the 'union all' but I'm looking for it on google

Comment: @Gauthier: You're either going to need to setup a table of sample data on a site like sqlfiddle.com, or provide the distinct patterns you are looking for or want solved for in your question.

Comment: @Gauthier: you should have directly edited your post, rather than posting an answer. My expression in my select statement should work on the sample data you posted, just replace test with your column name.